# A property on geodesic triangle involving the inverse of exponential map inverse

Tags: riemannian-geometry, geodesic

Let $(\mathcal{M}, g)$ be a complete manifold. Let $w\in \mathcal M$, $\xi_w\in T_w\mathcal M$ and
$$v= \operatorname{Exp}_w (\xi_w),$$
where $\operatorname{Exp}(\cdot)$ is the exponential map. Now let
$$w' = \text{Exp}_v (\xi'_v),$$
where $\xi'_v \in T_v\mathcal{M}$.

Assuming the inverse exponential map $\text{Exp}^{-1}$ is well defined, can we say that $\text{Exp}_w^{-1}(w') = \xi_w + T_v^w\xi'_v$, where $T_v^w$ is the parallel transport?

This is true in the simplest case, when $\mathcal M = \mathbb R^N$ is the Euclidean space with Euclidean metric. In this case, $\operatorname{Exp}_w(X) = w+X$ and $T^w_v = I$. Thus
$$v = w + \xi_w, w' = v + \xi_v,$$
so
$$w' = w + \xi_w + \xi_v \Rightarrow\operatorname{Exp}_w^{-1} (w') = \xi_w + \xi_v $$

Comment: No. It's too good to be true. Try to find a counterexample on sphere.

Comment: It will not be true globally, but assuming that inverse map is well defined and both $w$ and $w'$ are within the injectivity radius, I was hoping that this may be true but I am not able to find a reference or prove it.

Comment: That is not enough. Hint: assume $\xi_w \perp T_v^w\xi'_v$, $|\xi_w |=|\xi'_v|$. Then $w'$ must be distance $\sqrt 2 |\xi_w|$ away from $w$ if what you write is true. (That is, you need at least the Pyth. Theorem in the Euclidean space to hold)

Comment: I have edited your question to add some context, I hope you don't mind... (you can  rollback the edit anytime you like). Concerning your quesion,  I even guess that if your equality is true, the metric has to be flat.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, i also believe its only true for 0 curvature.